# Buttons getting misplaced after using background image in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Whenever I run this code with a background Image the button grid gets misplaced and pushed towards the bottom. Fortunately, it works as intended when no background is added .I want them to cover the background when executed. Pictures for reference are  added below. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
# importing the module
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import random
# importing the module

# initialising tkinter
class window(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
# initialising tkinter

# creating the window
root = Tk()
app = window(root)
root.geometry("630x630")
root.title('Odd Even Game')

C = Canvas(root, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "BG.png")
background_label = Label(root,image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

C.pack()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
# creating the window

# image
level_1e = "p1.png"
level_1o = "pe.png"
level_2e = "r1.png"
level_2o = "re.png"

# image   
def create_cards(odd_image,even_image,next_level,fno,order,suc,err,w,h):
    rx = random.randint(0,order-1)
    ry = random.randint(0,order-1)
    
    for i in range(0,order):
        for j in range(0,order):
            if i == rx and j == ry:
                create_button(i,j,suc,odd_image,next_level,fno,odd_image,w,h)
            else:
                create_button(i,j,err,even_image,next_level,fno,odd_image,w,h)
  
def second_level(fno):
    fno.pack_forget()
    frame2 = Frame(root)
    frame2.pack()
    suc = "Congratulations! You have cleared level 2..Keep Going Buddy!"
    err = "Wrong Answer..Don't give up yet!"
    create_cards(level_2o,level_2e,final_level,frame2,4,suc,err,157.5,157.5)

def final_level(fno):
    fno.pack_forget()
    root.geometry("700x700")
    ap = App(root)


# creating a button function
def create_button(x,y,msg,picture,next_level,fno,odd,w,h):
    if picture == odd:
        image = PhotoImage(file=picture)
        click = Button(fno, image=image, width= w, height=h, bd = 0,command = lambda : [score_update(),next_level(fno),tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Odd One Out Project",msg)])
        click.image = image
        click.grid( row = x, column = y)
        
    else:
        image = PhotoImage(file=picture)
        click = Button(fno, image=image, width= w, height=h, bd = 0,command = lambda : [next_level(fno),tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Odd One Out Project",msg)])
        click.image = image
        click.grid( row = x, column = y)

# creating a button function

def create_frame(fno):
    root.geometry("630x630")
    fno.pack_forget()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    suc = "Congratulations! You have cleared level 1..Time to increas[![enter image description here][1]][1]e the difficulty!"
    err = "Wrong Answer..Please Try again !!"
    create_cards(level_1o,level_1e,second_level,frame,3,suc,err,200,200)

def intro():
    root.geometry("630x630")
    frame0 = Frame(root)
    frame0.pack()
    click = Button(frame0,text="Start!" ,command = lambda [create_frame(frame0),tkinter.messagebox.showinfo( "Odd One Out Project","The game has begun!!")])
    click.pack()

intro()

# starting the widget
root.mainloop()
# starting the widget
```

[image: The Problem as I'm facing]

[image: The desired product]

The first image is the error. Second Image is the required output.
Note: I'm still a beginner in Python and Tkinter hence various terms and methods might be something out of my scope. Would be appreciated if taken into consideration.

In case needed, you might know that this is a tkinter project for picking the odd one out image out of A*A grid.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself so will be sharing for future use.

```
C = Canvas(root, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
```

This part draws a canvas of 250*300 dimensions hence does not let the buttons draw over it.

just change it to,

```
C = Canvas(root, bg="blue", height=0, width=0)
```

for the desired result